# Mac OS X: Backup IPhoto 6 while preserving albums

Tags: mac, backup, iphoto

I use IPhoto 6 version 6.0.6.  I have organized all of my photos into folders in IPhoto and Albums inside the folders.  I would like to make a backup of my phots and I would like them to be organized into albums.

Another way the phrase this question is like this: I have an older mac (pre-time machine).  I want to be able to make a backup on a dvd so that when my mac dies I will be able to restore all my IPhoto folders and albums.  Is there a way to do this?

*Edit:* Ideally the method should work with PCs as well.  Suppose I want to share my albums with a PC.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your iPhoto Library will fit on one DVD, the easiest way would be to simply burn the entire iPhoto Library onto a disk. If your Mac dies, you could drop the backup library into your Pictures folder on your new or repaired Mac and carry on smartly.

If the library is too big for a single DVD, yet you wish to keep it on that media, you would have to use the command line utility hdiutil with the -segmentSize option to create disk images that would fit on DVDs, then burn the images to individual disks. For more information, open the Terminal and enter "man hdiutil"

Comment: This directly answers the question provided that the iPhoto Library fits on the DVD. To add to this, when you need to restore, just copy the library from the DVD to wherever you would like to store it on the hard drive, and then double-click it to open it in iPhoto and select it as the default library.

Answer (score -1):

by far the best solution - photobox or other such online utility. WHy put yourself through hassle of extra HD storage when there are companies queueing to do it for you for FREE?!

Comment: Hi Neil, welcome to super user.  I am getting a definite spam alert on your post.  If this is not spam could you please give a brief description of what photobox is and fix your capitalization.